# How to update a JFrame from another JFrame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to update a JFrame from another JFrame. I have a basic program that has two similar interfaces with the same group name, I would like to know how I can code the program so if one person changes the group name it will automatically change on the other.

Thanks in advance

First interface

```
Public String groupNam;
private void groupNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
interface2 interface2 = new interface2();                                      
    groupNam = groupN.getText(); 
interface2.group.equals(groupNam); //interface2 is the class name of the other interface
}
```

Second interface

```
private void groupNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    groupName.getText().equals(groupNam); //calling the public string from interface 1 and placing it in groupName field
}
```

This was my attempt however it did not work.

Comment: Show us some relevant code that portrays your attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 3):

do you heard about the Observer pattern?

it might be the right thing for you.

Comment: [a tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

Comment: In addition, he should probably check out the whole MVC pattern. If he doesn't use the Observer pattern to communicate with the GUI, he probably makes other mistakes as well. (probably doesn't use a controller, etc)